# C++ cin with file instead of user input

Tags: c++, file, inputstream, cin

I have looked up what feels like every resource out there and I can't seem to find a solid answer to this question. Perhaps it's obvious, I am still new to C++.

I had the following functional main method:

```
int main()
{
    char firstChar, secondChar;
    cin >> firstChar;
    cin >> secondChar;
    cout << firstChar << " " << secondChar;

    system("pause"); // to wait for user input; allows the user to see what was printed before the window closes
    return 0;
}
```

This will cause the console to wait for input. The user inputs something. In this case `(test)`. The output is:

```
( t
```

I would like to change this so that the input comes from a file and can execute the same way for each line rather than just once.

I tried many variations of the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream filename(argv[0]);
    string line;
    char firstChar, secondChar;
    while (getline(filename, line))
    {
        cin >> firstChar;  // instead of getting a user input I want firstChar from the first line of the file.
        cin >> secondChar; // Same concept here.
        cout << firstChar << " " << secondChar;
    }

    system("pause"); // to wait for user input; allows the user to see what was printed before the window closes
    return 0;
}
```

This merely runs the while loop once for every line in the file, but still requires input into the console and in no way manipulates the data in the file.

File contents:

```
(test)
(fail)
```

Desired automatic output (without making the user enter `(test) and (fail)` manually:

```
( t
( f
```

Comment: I have added an answer but unless you show us an example of an input file I can only guess how it is formatted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final Edit**

After seeing the input I would do something like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream exprFile(argv[1]); // argv[0] is the exe, not the file ;)
    string singleExpr;
    while (getline(exprFile, singleExpr)) // Gets a full line from the file
    {
        // do something with this string now
        if(singleExpr == "( test )")
        {

        }
        else if(singleExpr == "( fail )") etc....
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You know what the full input is from the file so you can test the whole string at a time instead of character by character. Then just act accordingly once you have this string

Comment: There is one expression per line, but they can be rather complex so it's not so simple as just x + y. there can be nested ones as well etc. Previously I just handled this by extracting characters with `cin >> charVariable` and that would pull out the leftmost character. When it is a string, and not input, it changes everything.

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of the file layout

Comment: using `cin >> charVariable` causes the console to sit there waiting on user input. I want to use this same concept with an existing string. Something like `singleExpr >> charVariable` but that doesn't work.

Comment: No but you can iterate over the string character by character. Please paste in a copy of your file and I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @leigero See my edit for iterating over a string character by character. It sounds like behaviour like this that you desire

Answer (score 0):

The stream extraction operator, or '>>' would read from a stream till it finds a white-space. 
In C++, cin and cout are streams of types istream and ostream respectively. In your example, exprFile is an istream which when the file is opened, is successfully connected to the file you mention. To get one character at a time from a stream, you can do something as follows,

```
char paren;
paren = cin.get(); //For the cin stream.
paren = exprFile.get(); //for the exprStream stream, depending on your choice
```

To get more information, go through  [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

Comment: cppreference.com is the preferred site for referencing. The site you mention is rather poor

Comment: With the edited question's file contents `paren = filename.get();` prints out a dollar sign. The file's contents are `(test)`

Comment: Works for me. I get (, and not $

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream filename(argv[0]);
    string line;
    char firstChar, secondChar;
    while (getline(filename, line))
    {
        istringstream strm(line);
        strm >> firstChar;
        strm >> secondChar;
        cout << firstChar << " " << secondChar;
    }

    system("pause"); // to wait for user input; allows the user to see what was printed before the window closes
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: funny to see `filename(argv[0])` :)